# partition by multiple columns in Spark SQL not working properly

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, partition-by

I want to partition by three columns in my query :

1. user id
2. cancelation month year.
3. retention month year.

I used row number and partition by as follows

```
row_number() over (partition by user_id ,cast ( date_format(cancelation_date,'yyyyMM') as integer),cast ( date_format(retention_date,'yyyyMM') as integer) order by cast ( date_format(cancelation_date,'yyyyMM') as integer) asc, cast ( date_format(retention_date,'yyyyMM') as integer)   asc) as row_count
```

example of the output I got :

```
| user_id |cancelation_date |cancelation_month_year|retention_date|retention_month_year|row_count|
| -------- | -------------- |----------------------|--------------|--------------------|---------|
| 566      |      28-5-2020 |  202005              | 20-7-2020    | 202007             |1        |
| 566      |     28-5-2020  |  202005              | 30-7-2-2020  | 202007             |2        |
```

example of the output I want to get:

| user_id | cancelation_date | cancelation_month_year | retention_date | retention_month_year | row_count |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 566 | 28-5-2020 | 202005 | 20-7-2020 | 202007 | 1 |
| 566 | 28-5-2020 | 202005 | 30-7-2-2020 | 202007 | 1 |

note that user may have more than cancelation months, for example f he has canceled in August , I want row count =2 for all dates in August and so on.

it's not obvious why partition by is partitioning by retention date instead of partitioning by retention month year.

Comment: I get the impression `row_number` is not what you want, rather you are interested in [`dense_rank`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.functions.dense_rank.html?highlight=dense_rank), wherein you would get your expected output.

Comment: that's right . dense_rank worked for me

Comment: When you have a moment, if snithish answer worked for you, I'm sure they'd appreciate you marking it as correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I get the impression that `row_number` is not what you want, rather you are interested in [`dense_rank`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.functions.dense_rank.html?highlight=dense_rank), wherein you would get your expected output.